# Graphene Returning NoneType Error on Subscription

Tags: django, django-channels, graphene-django

I'm trying to setup subscription on graphene-django and channels using [channels_graphql_ws](https://github.com/datadvance/DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs).
I'm getting the following error when trying to run my subscription query:

```py
An error occurred while resolving field Subscription.onNewComment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/noroozim/.pyenv/versions/nexus37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql/execution/executor.py", line 450, in resolve_or_error
    return executor.execute(resolve_fn, source, info, **args)
  File "/Users/noroozim/.pyenv/versions/nexus37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql/execution/executors/sync.py", line 16, in execute
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/noroozim/.pyenv/versions/nexus37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels_graphql_ws/subscription.py", line 371, in _subscribe
    register_subscription = root.register_subscription
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register_subscription'
```

Here is what I have in my setup:

```py
# /subscription.py/

class OnNewComment(channels_graphql_ws.Subscription):

    comment = Field(types.UserCommentNode)

    class Arguments:
        content_type = String(required=False)

    def subscribe(root, info, content_type):
        return [content_type] if content_type is not None else None

    def publish(self, info, content_type=None):
        new_comment_content_type = self["content_type"]
        new_comment = self["comment"]
        return OnNewComment(
            content_type=content_type, comment=new_comment
        )

    @classmethod
    def new_comment(cls, content_type, comment):
        cls.broadcast(
            # group=content_type,
            payload={"comment": comment},
        )
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that graphne's graphiql template doesn't come with websocket support and I had to modify my `graphene/graphiql.html` file to incorporate websocket to get it to work.